# How can I avoid arrow function in Firebase Web Tutorial

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am looking to build a website that functions perfectly with most we browsers and uses firebase, however the arrow function that is used in the tutorial causes a syntax error in safari. How can I get around this? Thanks!

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

  var bigOne = document.getElementById('bigOne')
    var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('text');
  var text = new String('')
  dbRef.on('value', snap  => bigOne.innerText = snap.val()); //error occurs here
```

The error is SyntaxError: Unexpected Token '>'

Comment: Read the documentation on arrow functions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions It's well-explained there, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
dbRef.on('value', snap  => bigOne.innerText = snap.val());
```

with

```
dbRef.on('value', function(snap) {
  return bigOne.innerText = snap.val();
}
```

Comment: All I need to do to get this to work was add a close bracket after the return function. Thanks!